# Absolute Minimum of a Polynomial

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to $0$ and is a polynomial of an even degree. And there exists $g = f + f' + f'' + \cdots + f^{(n)}$ as $n$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$. Prove that $g$ has an absolute minimum in $\mathbb R$.

( $f(x)$ has domain and range of $\mathbb R$)

Comment: For any $n$? Or for a particular $n$?

Comment: According to the question the nth derivative from k =0 to to k=n.

Comment: That is *not* an answer to my question. What I want to know is this: is $n$ an arbitrary natural number? Or is $n$, say, the degree of $f$?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly it would be n the even degree of the polynomial but it is not specifically stated.

Comment: I doubt it. My guess is that $n$ is arbitrary. I could answer your question, but Hagen von Eitzen has already done that.

Comment: Same, it is a bit confusing. I saw it while I was studying for a test and it required a formal explanation

Comment: As Hagen von Eitzen wrote, the degree $n$ of $g$ is the degree of $f$, which is even. Besides, since $f(x)$ is greater than $0$, $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, with $a_n>0$. So, $g$ is also of the form $a_nx^n+\cdots$ (with the same $a_n$) and all you have to do is to prove that such a polynomial has an absolute minimum in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that $\deg g=\deg f$, so ... yes.

Comment: Could be noted that the condition $f(x) \ge 0$ is stronger than needed. It's enough that the dominant term has a positive coefficient.